# Is there any way to upload a photo/video and to check a direct message on instagram through a desktop browser?

Tags: instagram

I have a Business Instagram Account, but I'm unable to upload any media through the desktop Instagram web application. Is there any way apart from using the mobile application to upload the media on Instagram and to check the direct messages. Suggestions for third party tools and command line tools are welcome, would prefer free and open source software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"In early 2018, Instagram revised their API to allow third-party apps to post to Instagram in some circumstances. For now, it only works with Instagram business profiles, and while it adds the ability to schedule posts, not all of the usual Instagram features are available. Severeal social media management services like Buffer's, Sendible, and Hootsuite offer this functionality now."

https://havecamerawilltravel.com/photographer/uploading-photos-computer-instagram/

**[*dlvr*](https://dlvrit.com/)** appears to be an alternative to Buffer, though Instagram doesn't seem to be supported. APIs for most major platforms have undergone a change in July (possibly after the Facebook polls fiasco) and automation paradigms are likely to have to become smarter.